# Using ajax how can I pass variables to two different php scripts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have two forms that sends data using ajax. Both forms have their own scripts and I thought that I would be able to access the same `$_POST[]` variables on the separate scripts, but this is not working. I tried using `session_start()` and `include_once` and for some reason I can't figure out why the variables are not passing from script to script. I've been at it for three days researching for a solution so if you know what I'm doing wrong or have an alternative please let me know thanks.

javascript.

```
$('.test-input').load("test.php", {
    'sendTo':sendTo,
    'carrier':carrier,
    'testSubmit':testSubmit
  })

$('#error-display').load("textsms.php", {
    'date':scheduleDate,
    'firstname':firstName,
    'number':number,
    'message':message,
    'time':time,
    'service':service,
    'submit':submit
  })
```

test.php

```
if (isset($_POST['testSubmit'])) {
  $sendTo = $_POST['sendTo'];
  $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];

  $sendToInvalid = false;
  $testEmpty = false;
  $sendTo = "";

  if (!preg_match('/^\(?\b\d{3}[-.)\s]?\s?\d{3}[-.)\s]?\d{4}\b$/', $sendTo) and $sendTo !== '') {
    $sendToInvalid = true;
  } elseif (empty($sendTo) || empty($carrier)) {
    $testEmpty = true;
  } else {
    $sendTo = preg_replace('/[-.()\s]/','',$sendTo).$carrier;
    $_SESSION['sendTo'] = $sendTo;
  }
}
```

Trying to get `$sendTo` to pass to textsms.php down below.

```
else {
    include 'test.php';
    $sendTo = $_SESSION['sendTo'];
    $number = preg_replace('/[-.()\s]/','',$number);
    $number = "(".substr($number,0,3).") ".substr($number,3,3)."-".substr($number,6,4);
    if ($sendTo !== "contactme@aboutryansam.com") {
      $header = $name."\r\n#: ".$number;
      $sendMsg = $userMsg."\r\nOn: ".$date.$time."\r\nService: ".$service;

      //mail($sendTo, "You win!", $sendMsg, $header);
      echo $sendTo;
      echo "it worked";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, on the page you initialize the ajax, include the "header.php" file that has inside `session_start()`. `include_once('header.php')` in the test.php as well. It should do the trick.

It's not a good practice nowadays, I better suggest you to use cookies and access them with `$_COOKIE`. Even better, use a library that takes care of cookies like [this one](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). JQuery also has very good cookie management.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb I've wasted so much time on this. I thought you only put session_start() on the page with the actual HTML so I didn't put it on either of the scripts. I thought that everything was suppose to pass through the javascript through the the ajax requests. So just to clarify the solution was to put session_start() at the top of every .php file. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, or you put `session_start()` and any other session related code in one file and include that file everywhere.